# Can I use this circuit for a 15V voltage inverter using TC962 charge pump controller?

Tags: charge-pump

I need a +/-15V, 45mA source to power some current sensors.

I think Microchip's TC962 ([datasheet](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/21484D.pdf)) would be suitable to provide a -15V rail.

I had a look at the datasheet but they don't specifically show a voltage inverter circuit, only a 'Combined Negative Converter and Positive Multiplier' on page 5. I think I can just leave out part of this circuit, like in the attached screenshot, but I just wanted to make sure.

[image: Edited screenshot from datasheet]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figure 3-1 from the datasheet is what you want.

[image]

That generates a negative voltage from the positive supply.

The datasheet doesn't mention any requirement to generate a positive as well as a negative voltage.  The TC962 shouldn't have any trouble generating just a negative voltage.

You could also refer to the drawing "Lowering Output Resistance by Paralleling Devices."  That shows two negative output inverters in parallel.  Each of the inverters is nothing more than the simplest application of the TC962:

[image]

Both are pretty much the same as your proposed circuit.